# Intent in Timer Task causes force close

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, manifest

So I'm writing an app which, when plugged in, is supposed to launch an activity telling the user to unplug the device from a computer. In this class, I have a timer which periodically checks to see if it is plugged in. The code in the timer works other than when I try to start another activity when the user disconnects the cord. I am not sure if the issue lies in the class with the timer, or the Manifest, although the activity which I am trying to launch when disconnect was working earlier and I haven't made any changes to it.

Here is the code for the **StateCheck** class (tests whether its plugged in by checking the state of the SD card):

```
public class StateCheck extends Activity {

TextView stateCheck, unmountedImage, tester;
Timer timer;
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.state_check);
    stateCheck = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStateCheck);
    unmountedImage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUnmountedImage);
    tester = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTester);

    //Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.flannigan.MUSERCISEACTIVITY");
    //startActivity(openStartingPoint);

    MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(myTask, 1000);
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
          i++;

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                unmountedImage.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        unmountedImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                stateCheck.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        stateCheck.setText("SD card is mounted!\nLoading...");
                    }
                });
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.flannigan.MUSERCISEACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);           
            } else {
                MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(myTask, 1000);
                tester.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tester.setText(""+i);
                    }
                });
            }
      }
}
}
```

**Manifest**:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".StateCheck"
        android:label="Musercise"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.flannigan.STATECHECK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MuserciseActivity"
        android:label="Musercise"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.flannigan.MUSERCISEACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: when you get forceclose error. its always suggested to post your stack trace

Comment: @Owen2014 please post logcat errors.

Comment: @Owen2014 are you sure it is going inside of this condition `if(mOrientation == FULLSCREEN)` in your popup script?

Comment: Hey, sorry guys, I feel really stupid now because i just realized that the error was in the MuserciseActivity class that I was trying to launch into. I'm still not sure why it is crashing though, since it wasn't earlier, and i haven't made any changes to the code. I assume that something in this new class is interfering with it and causing it to crash. Thanks for the help and the tips anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for Accessing UI elements from TimerTask Thread as:

```
StateCheck.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){

             // start next Activity here
             // Access UI element here

            }          
        });
```

and for Starting Activity Change your Intent as:

```
Intent intent=new (StateCheck.this,MuserciseActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```